# Django Rest Framework: Updating subobject with new route, not partial update to model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API object, Roster, which has a list of Members as a subobject on it. However, I do not want to update the subobject by partially updating the Roster object -- instead, I want a route for "add member" and "remove member".

Goal:

`GET /Roster/{ROSTERID}`

response body:

```
{
    id: {roster id},
    members: # members sub object is read only
      [
        {member subobject},
        {member subobject},
         ...
      ],
}
```

`POST /Roster/{RosterID}/AddMember`

```
{
    {member id},
    {member id}, ...
}
```

and then a similar thing for removing a member.

Note: I want to be able to pass a existing member id in. I don't want to create new members here.

What should I be looking for in the docs to be able to add a route to update the member list with a user id, instead of having to pass in the whole user object?

`serializers.py`

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']

class RosterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.ListField(
        child=UserSerializer()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Roster
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'members')
        depth = 2
```

`app/models.py`

```py
class Members(User):
    on_pto = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Roster(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, default='', unique=True, null='')
    members = models.ForeignKey(
        Members,
        limit_choices_to={'on_pto': False},
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='members',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

`views.py`

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer


class RosterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """"""

    queryset = Roster.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = RosterSerializer
```

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: SInce you are using `ModelViewSet` views (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) you will need to override the `update` method in your `RosterViewSet` class.  Might might be a good idea to post your `urls.py` file.

Comment: Also you might want to change your models so that `User` has a FK to Roster instead of `Roster` having a FK to `User`.  That way in your `update` method would simply create `User` records with the FK set to the pk of the Roster.

Comment: Also it might make things easier if you added a "operation" field to your payload. Where operations is either `add` or `subtract`.

Comment: @klreeher, did you have a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to **change your models to allow multiple members for a roster**, either do a many-to-many for roster or put the FK relationship on the user. So you can then add multiple members for a roster.

To do that you can use a custom route like this. Showing below for add_member and then similarly for remove_member, modify to delete from members_set for roster object.

```
class RosterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Roster.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = RosterSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def add_member(self, request, pk=None):
        errors = []
        response = {}
        roster = self.get_object()
        members_dict = request.data['members']
        if not isinstance(members_dict, list):
            errors.append("Invalid request format")
        else:
            for id in members_dict:
                try:
                    member = User.objects.get(pk=id)
                    roster.members.add(member)
                    roster.save()
                    status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
                except Member.DoesNotExist:
                    errors.append("Member id {} not found".format(id))
         if errors:
            response['errors'] = errors
            status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

    return response.Response(response, status=status_code)
```